# I am trying to dynamically create a Mui icon using React.createElement. However, React lowercases the element. Is there a way to keep case?

Tags: reactjs, dom, dynamic, material-ui, element

I am getting service.icon from JSON, so it looks like so

```
[
  {
    "icon": "AdminPanelSettingsIcon",
  }
]
```

I am using React.createElement() like so,

```
data.map((service) => {
  let icon = React.createElement(
    service.icon, 
    { key: service.icon }, 
    null);
});
```

my output is  `<adminpanelsettingsicon></adminpanelsettingsicon>`

**is there anyway to keep case, or convert to PascalCase so it renders like so** `<AdminPanelSettingsIcon></AdminPanelSettingsIcon>`

Note: Is there anyway to dynamically display mui icons based on specified JSON aka api call.

Comment: What is the `service` identifier?

Comment: I am getting it from the json, so it would be. `"icon": "AdminPanelSettingsIcon"`

Comment: Its not jsx, I am using React.createElement() to create an element.   https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html

Comment: React trying to deal like 'div' with the string!!!! ("adminpanelsettingsicon")
Are your icons currently components? I mean, do you have any icon component(s)?!

Comment: Yes those icon components are mui components, they can be imported and used directly. https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons/?msclkid=6ab5f0a2d0e911ecb5d1327d6dcaaf69  however, I want to dynamically build the icons based on the JSON that I receive.

Comment: @V.Villacis Just create a component which returns the MUI-icon related to icon (from server) you are passing to it. It will work.

Comment: @AdelArmand I know it will work, but I don't wan to do it that way. I want to create it dynamically with the JSON

Comment: @V.Villacis You want to pass a string to createElement and expect it to find/create the icon you want!! No way :))

Comment: @AdelArmand  the string is the name of the icon. The icon element is based on the string. I am halfway there with my output, I just need it to be in pascal case, once it is in pascal case, I think it will render since I am importing the icon in the file already.

Comment: You can receive any type of Icon from the server or there is a limited number of icons? I think the best approach here is to create an object where the key of object is the string recceived from server and the value is the Icon Component related, and with this you can render the correct Icon with sometinhg like: `const Component = object[service.icon]`

Comment: @V.Villacis is your output predictable? Like `service.icon` just an item in an array component? `AdminPanelSettingsIcon` component is your defined component or library?

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) specify:

```
React.createElement(
  type,
  [props],
  [...children]
)
```

> The type argument can be either a tag name string (such as 'div' or
> 'span'), a React component type (a class or a function), or a React
> fragment type.

You're attempting to create an element using the string `"AdminPanelSettingsIcon"`. Instead you should be attempting this by passing in the class:

```
React.createElement(AdminPanelSettingsIcon)
```

You can do this by converting your list to use classes as the value:

```
[
  {
    // The value is a class now, not a string
    "icon": AdminPanelSettingsIcon,
  }
]
```

Comment: Hmmm the problem is that the JSON is an api that is being called. I am doing this on the front end, I do not have access to the backend. So I cannot change the icon string.....I am getting ```<adminpanelsettingsicon></adminpanelsettingsicon>``` this rendered when I inspect the element. Its just not camelcase though.  Perhaps if I call the api and push it into an array and then save it to state and then pass it down without strings. I'll try .

Answer (score 1):

**Update**:

If you are using `https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/icons` (or any other library), you can dynamically import all of the components like this:

```js
//Preparing, it should run inside async function
let maps = {}
let listIcon = [];
await import('@material-ui/icons').then(res => {
      listIcon = res
})

for(let icon of listIcon){
    maps[icon.constructor.name.toLowerCase()] = icon;
}

//Render
data.map((service) => {
    const component = maps[service.icon] || DefaultComponent;
    let icon = React.createElement(
        component,
        { key: component },
        null);
});
```

**Original answer**:

If the API output is predictable (`service.icon` is just a component of the components you defined)

You can do this:

```js
//Import...

//Defined maps
const maps = {
    "adminpanelsettingsicon": AdminPanelSettingsIcon,
    "adminpanelsettingsicon2": AdminPanelSettingsIcon2,
    "adminpanelsettingsicon3": AdminPanelSettingsIcon3,
}

//Render
data.map((service) => {
    const component = maps[service.icon] || DefaultComponent;
    let icon = React.createElement(
        component,
        { key: component },
        null);
});
```

It'll work as you wish

Answer (score 0):

**Simple way** to do this,

In your `.jsx` file :

```
import Icon from '@mui/material/Icon';

export default function MyComponent() {
  const iconName = `home`
  return (<Icon>{iconName}</Icon>);
}
```

As a prerequisite, you must include this line in yout `index.html`

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Voilà !

Sources :

- [Mui DOC](https://mui.com/material-ui/icons/#icon-font-icons)